# Dynamically added jQuery RateIt not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, rating-system

I have an MVC application with form data in a partial view, populated via Ajax.
In this form, I have a `select` for which I need a star rating system.

That does work.

What does not work is: I need to be able to clone both the select and its rating system, so that I then have two selects with a star rating each. (Add item, basically).

Adding the first RateIt is pretty simple:

```
<span class="rateit" id="rateit0"></span>
```

The fancy parts get rendered automatically later. I have encapsulated the select and its rating by a div, so I can simply create the clone with JQuery like this:

```
var klon = $(item).closest('div').clone(true);
```

After that I make sure all IDs in the clone are updated so that I can properly identify each component. Works fine, at least for the select.
What does not work though is the rating system. I do get a second RateIt accompanying my newly created select - but I cannot set any value. All hovering causes the *first* rating to update.

Here is what my two RateIts look like after cloning:

```
<span class="rateit" id="rateit0">
  <button id="rateit-reset-2" type="button" data-role="none" class="rateit-reset" aria-label="reset rating" aria-controls="rateit-range-2"></button>
  <span aria-readonly="false" style="width: 80px; height: 16px;" id="rateit-range-2" class="rateit-range" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-label="rating" aria-owns="rateit-reset-2" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5" aria-valuenow="0">
    <span id="select0" class="rateit-selected" style="height: 16px; width: 0px;"></span>
    <span id="hover0" class="rateit-hover" style="height: 16px; width: 0px; display: none;"></span>
  </span>
</span>
```

and

```
<span class="rateit" id="rateit1">
  <button id="rateit-reset-21" type="button" data-role="none" class="rateit-reset" aria-label="reset rating" aria-controls="rateit-range-21"></button>
  <span aria-readonly="false" style="width: 80px; height: 16px;" id="rateit-range-21" class="rateit-range" tabindex="1" role="slider" aria-label="rating" aria-owns="rateit-reset-21" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5" aria-valuenow="0">
    <span id="select1" class="rateit-selected" style="height: 16px; width: 0px;"></span>
    <span id="hover1" class="rateit-hover" style="height: 16px; width: 0px; display: none;"></span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Here, I have guessed what needs to be adapted and settled on `aria-owns` and `aria-controls` as well as ids.

After the cloning is done, I conclude by activating the RateIts (or at least so I think) and bind the tooltips:

```
$('.rateit').each(function() {
    $(this).rateit();
    $(this).bind('over', function (event, value) { $(this).attr('title', tooltipvalues[value - 1]); });
});
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you add more than one, does it still only cause the first rating to update?

Comment: Affirmative. I just tested this and no matter how many I add, it only updates the first one. BUT: The `rateit-reset`button highlights properly on hover, i.e. if I hover of the third one, only the third one gets highlighted. I also checked whether it is just a display issue but indeed only the first holds a value even after clicking each rating.

Comment: Try pulling out the rateit init of the each and add `$('.rateit').rateit();` afterwards

Comment: Absolutely no difference.

Comment: Put a counter in your each loop and see how many times it loops, also try removing the true flag in your .clone call

Comment: The counter tells me it iterates correctly over all rateits.
If I remove the `true` from `clone()` I get `uncaught exception: Can't set value before init`
I think, maybe I should remove the rateit from the clone, replace it with the original, unexpanded `span`of class rateit and then call init on that new rateit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. One must not leave the existing RateIt in the clone and try to adapt IDs there. The events will not be properly bound then.

You must remove the RateIt from the clone, append/insert a fresh, unitialized RateIt span at the proper position and initialize it:

```
var klon = $(item).closest("div").clone(true);
var tmp = $(klon).find("select").each(function () {
            $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) { return id.replace(oldnum, newnum) },
                    'name': function (_, name) { return name.replace(oldnum, newnum) }
                });
    }).end();
tmp.find(".rateit").each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    }).end();

$(item).closest("td").append(tmp);
    $('<span class="rateit" id="rateit' + newnum + '" data-rateit-step="1"></span>').insertAfter("#Subject" + newnum);
    $("#rateit" + newnum).rateit();
```

Et voilà.